# Angular: what is the best way to import formly lib?

Tags: angular, angular-formly

In my app I'm having several lazy-loaded modules that use formly library. I'm try to import and re-export formly module in `CoreModule` (that is loaded eagerly and imported in `AppModule`)

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormlyModule.forRoot({ extras: { lazyRender: true } }),
        FormlyMaterialModule
    ],
    providers: [
        AwesomeService1,
        AwesomeService2
    ],
    exports: [
        FormlyModule,
        FormlyMaterialModule
    ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

However when I try to use `formly-form` components declared inside `FormlyModule` it's not rendered. If I add imports of `FormlyModule` and `FormlyMaterialModule` everything works as it should. But obviously adding imports to each lazy module is not a good solution as it will increase bundles size. Adding imports and re-export to `SharedModule` (that is imported in each of lazy modules) will also add formly to each bundle (with other stuff in `SharedModule`).

The question is, what's the best solution of my problem?